# Javascript documentwrite function escaped

Tags: javascript, escaping, javascript-framework

have line like this and the onLoad function parameters are reporting error:

```
document.write("document.getElementById(\"my_iframe\").innerHTML = '<iframe src=\"http://MyDomain.com/index.php?accessing_from=\'+loc+\'\" style=\"border: none; min-height: 60px;\" onload=\"resizeCrossDomainIframe(\'iframe\', \'http://MyDomain.com\');\"> </iframe>'  ");
```

The part that bothers me is `onload=\"resizeCrossDomainIframe(\'iframe\', \'http://MyDomain.com\');\"`

I get error with this setup but when I remove function parameters and leave it like `resizeCrossDomainIframe()`  everything works OK (in terms of document writing, but function is not working as it's not passing parameters), so my question is why this won't work when parametars are escaped ?

----------------------EDITED ------------------------

Ok, on MyDomain.com I have file create_iframe.js with this:

```
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id, other_domain) { var iframe = document.getElementById(id);  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {if (event.data === \"reload\") top.location.reload(); if (event.origin !== other_domain) return;  if (isNaN(event.data)) return;  var height = parseInt(event.data) + 40; iframe.height = height + \"px\"; }, false); }</script> ");
document.write("<div id=\"wwiz_rooster\"></div>");
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
document.write("var loc = window.location.host; ");
document.write("loc = \"http://\"+loc;");
document.write("alert(loc);");
document.write("document.getElementById(\"wwiz_rooster\").innerHTML = '<iframe src=\"MyDomain.com/index.php?accessing_from=\'+loc+\'\" style=\"border: none; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; width:986px; min-height: 60px;\" onload=\"resizeCrossDomainIframe(\\'rooster_iframe\\', \\'http://MyDomain.com\\');\"> </iframe>'  ");
document.write("</script>");
```

EDIT: STUPID ME.... FORGOT TO ASSIGN ACTUAL ID TO IFRAME !!!! ANWAY - ALL WORKS WELL ! AND THANKS FOR HELP !!!!!!

Comment: You have not ended with double quotes `onload=\"resizeCrossDomainIframe(\'iframe\', \'http://MyDomain.com\')";` and do not use escape sequence, directly use ' (single quote)

Comment: Why do you have JavaScript in your `document.write()`?

Comment: I want to host script on my server and just give the users one line code to integrate iframe... (as there is a lot more scripts lines, but i just pasted faulty line)

Comment: @asifsid88 - look at the code ...for some reason stack cuted that part in text, but it shows in code line...

Comment: insert the entire tag in a variable and call it inside the document.write

Comment: Should the first param to resizeCrossDomainIframe be **my_iframe** rather than `iframe` ?

Comment: How many levels of nested string literals do you want? You are having js strings in an onload attribute of an iframe string inside the written string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many nested string literals whose quotes are not properly escaped. Watch it grow:

```js
resizeCrossDomainIframe('iframe', 'http://MyDomain.com');
```

```xml
<iframe src="http://MyDomain.com/index.php?…"
  style="border: none; min-height: 60px;"
  onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('iframe', 'http://MyDomain.com');"
></iframe>
```

```
document.getElementById("my_iframe").innerHTML =
'<iframe src="http://MyDomain.com/index.php?accessing_from='+loc+'" \
  style="border: none; min-height: 60px;" \
  onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe(\'iframe\', \'http://MyDomain.com\');" \
></iframe>'
```

```
"document.getElementById(\"my_iframe\").innerHTML = \
  '<iframe src=\"http://MyDomain.com/index.php?accessing_from=\'+loc+\'\" \
    style=\"border: none; min-height: 60px;\" \
    onload=\"resizeCrossDomainIframe(\\'iframe\\', \\'http://MyDomain.com\\');\" \
  ></iframe>' \
"
```

You forgot to double-up the backslashes in the last iteration. You are already lucky that you could mix apostrophes with double quotes, else it would have become such a nightmare that you woke up from your folly:

```
"document.getElementById(\"my_iframe\").innerHTML = \
  \"<iframe src=\\\"http://MyDomain.com/index.php?accessing_from=\"+loc+\"\\\" \
    style=\\\"border: none; min-height: 60px;\\\" \
    onload=\\\"resizeCrossDomainIframe(&quot;iframe&quot;, &quot;http://MyDomain.com&quot;); \\\" \
  ></iframe>\" "
```

Btw, the third iteration looks wrong to me. Why would you want to write plain JS in your document? If you want to output it, better put it inside `<pre>` tags but don't write it from JavaScript. And if you wanted to execute it (which you don't unless you put a `document.write("<script>")` before it), just execute it - never handle code as strings!

---

Regarding your goal to publish a script that creates an iframe on the current site, that script should just have the following content:

```
var loc = …;
document.write('<iframe src="http://MyDomain.com/index.php?accessing_from='+loc+'" \
  style="border: none; min-height: 60px;" \
  onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe(\'iframe\', \'http://MyDomain.com\');" \
></iframe>');
```

Try to include that into a test page.

Comment: Yes, I want to execute it and it just won't work no matter what I do. Goal is to place one script file on my server and give users url to place inside their site, so script shold output everything inside their code... But nothing works :(

Comment: Actually I had that... so the problem now is different... I will update this question in few minutes.

Comment: @Peter: Or rather make it a new question

Comment: I just think for future reference (if somebody has same problem as I do) it would be easier for them to track this :)

Comment: Thanks... all is well now ! forgot to add actuall ID to created iframe :(